# Customizing out of the box angular tabs

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to customize some of the out of the box styles from Angular Material 14. So far I have been able to change the tab colors, and background colors. But how do I change the blue active bar?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-twq7kg?file=src/app/tab-group-basic-example.css

I would like to know how to to customize the blue active bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.mat-tab-group.mat-primary .mat-ink-bar, 
.mat-tab-nav-bar.mat-primary .mat-ink-bar {
  background-color: red;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
::ng-deep .mat-ink-bar {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```